# How to invoke the process function immediately in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple of apache-flink code like this:

```java
// Parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
DataStream<WordWithCount> windowCounts = source
        .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                for (String word : value.split(" ")) {
                    out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1));
                }
            }
        })
        .keyBy("word")
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(PROCESSING_WINDOW_TIME))
        .process(new WordProcessingWindowFunction());
```

In the flatMap function if I find a condition of the word and I want to trigger the process function immediately, how can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's say I want to call the process function every 5 minutes, however, the window is collecting records in the second minute and the map function finds that the current element meets the calculation's condition. This time I want to fire the process function immediately instead waiting more 3 minutes to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom trigger to fire the time window in case of expected elements.

```
.timeWindow(Time.seconds(PROCESSING_WINDOW_TIME))
.trigger(new YourCustomTrigger())
.xxx
```

Comment: I'm new of Flink, so could you write a pseudocode that shows the combination of map, trigger and process functions. The code will call WordProcessingWindowFunction from the trigger function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could split the stream after the flatMap (or replace the flatMap with a ProcessFunction that uses a side output), and send one output stream through the window and its ProcessWindowFunction, and send the other stream with the special words through some other (related) function(s). In the end you could use a union to fuse the streams back together, if desired.